# Spring Boot adding envelope in request for SOAP integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, header, integration-testing

I am trying to make SOAP integration tests. I have an XML file as a request and in SOAPUI it has a soap envelope header and footer as follows :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.billing.nulogix.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:analyze>
         <ser:studyContainer>
<![CDATA[
```

and

```
]]>
         </ser:studyContainer>
         <ser:studyContainerVersion>3.17.6.12</ser:studyContainerVersion>
      </ser:analyze>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to include this in the integration test. So far I did this:

```
private String studyDetailDemo;

    private String header = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ser=\"http://service.billing.nulogix.com\">\n" + 
            "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" + 
            "   <soapenv:Body>\n" + 
            "      <ser:analyze>\n" + 
            "         <ser:studyContainer>\n" + 
            "<![CDATA[\n";
    private String footer = "]]>\n" + 
            "         </ser:studyContainer>\n" + 
            "         <ser:studyContainerVersion>3.17.6.12</ser:studyContainerVersion>\n" + 
            "      </ser:analyze>\n" + 
            "   </soapenv:Body>\n" + 
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

    private String request = header + studyDetailDemo + footer;
    @Test
    public void soapTest() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        String result = Request.Post("https://127.0.0.1:28443/nulogix/ws/billingtool")
                .connectTimeout(2000)
                .socketTimeout(2000)
                .bodyString(request, ContentType.TEXT_XML)
                .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

When I run this in mvn I get this error though:

```
StudyDetails unmarshal failed due to JAXBException javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.]
```